# Create cmd command with parameters in batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a cmd command by writing a batchfile and put it into "system32" to call it in the cmd console by its name. Is there a way to expect parameters in the batch file:

Write in cmd:

```
fake-command Test
```

And then work with the string "Test" in the batch file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%1` to access the first argument, `%2` for the second, etc.